# How to show "/foobar match 1 of " or "E486: Pattern not found: foobar" in commandline when calling `normal! n` in function

Tags: vimscript, command-line, normal-mode, echo

I'm calling `normal! n` in a vimscript function.

If there is a match, I don't get the message `/foobar match 1 of 3` in the commandline.

If there is no match, my commandline shortly flickers up and down and calling `:messages` reveals the output

`Error detected while processing function <SNR>1_contextn:
line    6:
E486: Pattern not found: foobar`

How could I show the success message and the last line of that error message just as they are shown when `n` is pressed normally?

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of the function, how youre calling, &c.? Details are relevant. (I suspect you’ve `silent`’ed it.)

Comment: @DBenKnoble darn, you are right. The problem is: I am calling multiple functions in the `nnoremap` command. I want some of them silent, but not others.

Comment: Sounds like you need to go through and individually silence commands, or live with the silence. Again, details here would help immensely in designing the right solution.

Comment: Ive voted to close since you asked a new question, but in general the expectation is that you [edit] a question to improve it