# How to get the same message and error behavior as normal `n` when calling `normal n` in function?

Tags: vimscript, search, normal-mode, debugging

I wrote a vimscript function that prevents the cursor from changing its location on the screen when I press `n`:

```
function! s:my_n()
    let l:start=line("w0")
    let end = line("w$")
    let cursor = line(".")
    let from_top = cursor-l:start
    normal! n
    let new_start = line("w0")
    let new_end = line("w$")
    let new_cursor = line(".")
    let new_from_top = new_cursor-new_start
    if new_from_top>from_top
        for i in range(new_from_top-from_top)
            execute "normal! \<C-e>"
        endfor
    else
        for i in range(from_top-new_from_top)
            execute "normal! \<C-y>"
        endfor
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap n :call <SID>my_n()<CR>
```

Everything works fine, except for the messages:

I'd want the same as a normal `n`, namely:

- When there is a match, get `.. match x out of y`
- When there is no match, get `E486 Pattern not found: ...`

Instead, what I get is:

- If I press `n` directly after the `/` command and when there is a match, I get `:call <SNR>1_my_n()` in the command line, but once I move away from matches and then press `n` again, I don't get anything at all anymore.
- When there is no match, the command line grows in size and displays

  Error detected while processing function 1_contextn:
  line    6:
  E486: Pattern not found: asdfsdf
  Press ENTER or type command to continue

I tried a few things:

(A) Use `silent normal! n`

Nothing changes

(B) Use `silent! normal! n`

When there is no match, I don't get an error message anymore and instead get `:call <SNR>1_my_n()`

(C) Use `map <silent> n` and go back to `normal! n`

- When there is a match, I get the proper message `.. match x out of y`, but once I leave the matches and then press `n` I don't get anything at all
- Same behavior as in the original when there are no matches

(D) Use `map <silent> n` and `silent normal! n`

Exactly as (C)

(E) Use `map <silent> n` and `silent! normal! n`

- When there is a match, same as in (C)
- When there is no match, no message or error at all

---

Note: This question is basically the same as  [How to show "/foobar match 1 of " or "E486: Pattern not found: foobar" in commandline when calling `normal! n` in function](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/18583/how-to-show-foobar-match-1-of-or-e486-pattern-not-found-foobar-in-comman?noredirect=1#comment32125_18583) but cleaned up, with the complete code, and with all my attempts. In comparison to that question, I am omitting here another complexity, namely that my full mapping is
`nnoremap n :call <SID>my_n()<CR><SID>my_other_function()<CR>` and if the solution to my problem involves changing this mapping, it'd be also good to know how to control the output of the two function calls separately

Comment: confused, because printing "match x out of y" is not normal vim behavior

Comment: @Mass, I'm sorry, I guess that's a plug-in that I installed, I'll figure that out later and update the question

Answer (score 0):

You can add `try...endtry` block for your `normal! n`:

```
function! s:my_n()
    let l:start=line("w0")
    let end = line("w$")
    let cursor = line(".")
    let from_top = cursor-l:start
    try
        normal! n
    catch
        echohl ErrorMsg
        echo substitute(v:exception, '^Vim(.*):', '', '')
        echohl NONE
    endtry
    let new_start = line("w0")
    let new_end = line("w$")
    let new_cursor = line(".")
    let new_from_top = new_cursor-new_start
    if new_from_top>from_top
        for i in range(new_from_top-from_top)
            execute "normal! \<C-e>"
        endfor
    else
        for i in range(from_top-new_from_top)
            execute "normal! \<C-y>"
        endfor
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap n :call <SID>my_n()<CR>
```